# Lazarus Pascal on Android - performance

Tags: java, android, performance, lazarus

Although a long-time developer, I've never seriously used an Android device - let alone programming one. So I'm new to this platform.

I'm looking at Lazarus for Android and found [this link](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Custom_Drawn_Interface/Android) that has the following lines:

> LCL-CustomDrawn-Android utilizes a minimal Java application which
>   communicates with our Pascal library and sends all events to it and
>   also obeys commands from it.

This raises a bunch of question for me.

1. In other words, is Lazarus running on the Android like a Windows app running on Wine (for Linux)?
2. If Java has to get in the way, wouldn't it be faster to directly run Java code without creating Lazarus/Pascal code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In other words, is Lazarus running on the Android like a Windows app 
>       running on Wine (for Linux)?

No. While there is a light preference for Java, native is quite common on Android, and they all need to connect to OS services via a Java skeletal application.

> If Java has to get in the way, wouldn't it be faster to directly 
>       run Java code without creating Lazarus/Pascal code?

No. The code that runs is native, only GUI events trigger some minimal java overhead.

Comment: @Marco so am I correct to guess that (as we know) native Pascal code should finally run through a Java VM (which is interpreter driven)? And wouldn't the entire Pascal app come down to the speed of interpreted bytecode? A little confused here :/

Comment: No, the Java VM is JIT, and the Java VM has no control over the native pascal code till it returns. Of course it can hold up when the pascal code calls into Java, but that is no different from any OS call.

Answer (score 0):

The ARM CPUs on phones can execute Java bytecode natively, it's built into their instruction set.  So it doesn't need to run through an interpreter like on Windows or Linux.  Java doesn't provide such a speed penalty there as everywhere else.  That's not true of x86 Android but ARMs were built partly to run Java.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualcomm_Snapdragon

Answer (score -1):

> Is Lazarus running on the Android like a Windows app running on Wine (for Linux)?

Actually, it sounds more like a Java (Swing) application running in Windows. Swing is known for drawing its own controls, rather than using the controls provided by the host operating system (OS). The only connection between Swing and the host OS (Windows, etc) is the window chrome around the application and how the host OS controls this window chrome.

> If Java has to get in the way, wouldn't it be faster to directly run Java code without creating Lazarus/Pascal code?

It would be faster, as Android is natively based on Java. In fact, if you can write Android apps in Java, I recommend you to pick that as your first choice. [Start here to learn the basics.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)

I believe the purpose of this Lazarus/Pascal library is to help run Pascal apps on Android, or otherwise help Pascal programmers write apps for Android. It may also help write apps where any limitations of Java would require the use of Pascal.

To take the analogy further, C++ and C# apps generally run faster on Windows as the OS is natively based on these languages. However, many applications are still written in Java using Swing interface for various advantages such as programmer familiarity or cross-platform availability of the app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and link. A little doubt though... You said '`C++ and C# apps generally run faster on Windows as the OS is natively based on these languages.`' But even if I wrote native code in Basic or Pascal, once compiled, I think they'll all be in maching code. So I don't see how C++ or C# will be any better on the OS. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'll admit I'm not very knowledgeable about the subject, but seeing as you don't have an answer, I added one. Windows is written in C++ (I'm not sure if latest Windows like 8 or 8.1 has parts in C#). I was making the comparison with Java Swing, which was known for being terribly slow in older versions, especially with poorly written code (Looks like things have improved). Unlike Basic or Pascal which are compiled to machine code like C++ is, Java is compiled to a "virtual-machine code" which runs in a JVM. The only way Java can run as fast as native is if it has a JVM as fast as the host.

Comment: Besides, I get the impression you are starting in Android app development for the first time. If all you need to do is learn how to develop for Android, I suggest you stick to doing it in Java as that is what Google intended. Unless you have a really good reason for doing it in Pascal/Lazarus. Sure, you may be very comfortable in Pascal and a total newbie in Java, but Java (on Dalvik VM) is native for Android, and it's also easy to pick up.

Comment: **Note:** My first comment talks about running Java in Windows, which requires installation of JVM. Windows is not natively designed to run a JVM efficiently. In my second comment, I mention Dalvik VM. This is an integral part of Android (at its heart *if you will*), and Android is natively designed from ground-up to run this efficiently.

Comment: All "fast" app use native code. Java is not magically fast on Android. Easier maybe, but not faster.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort the question is about performance and I'd like to accept your thought that Java is not faster. But do you admit that Java is easier for the Android, despite you being a Lazarus/Delphi person?

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Nobody talks about magic here. The [Dalvik VM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)) is specially designed to run Java code natively fast. It uses Java bytecode which has been converted to Dalvik bytecode, which is specifically optimized for devices running Android. So yes, Java is fast on Android, and no it's not magically fast unless you consider Dalvik to be magical.

Comment: @ADTC I think what Marco is saying is that since Pascal is a *native language*, it compiles and runs faster than Java because Java is ultimately run as an *interpreted language* since the VM converts bytecode at run-time. So Java bytecode on **any** VM cannot be faster than native executables until the Java code is itself brought into executable form.

Comment: itsols: Sure it is easier. But that was not the question of the OP.

Comment: ADTC: "Natively" fast for bytecode is nonsense, and yes Dalvik has a few minor tweaks relative to J2ME, but nothing fundamental. Mostly it only cuts legacy and optimizes manually for ARM. The strong point of using Java is more that the features of the exact processor (architecture) you are running are automatically taken care of, something that requires a separate binary per arch in the native case. But a bytecode managed language with GC can't touch a native binary for that processor with manual management. At best it doesn't matter.